# chain two remote tasks in celery by send_task

Tags: python, celery

In celery I want to chain two tasks from remote worker together. Can somebody tell me how to specify it in send_task? Or is there any other way of calling remote tasks?

BR

Answer (score 9):

I was attempting to do the same thing.  I couldn't find any built-in functionality to generate a task purely by its name, however it wasn't difficult to add such tooling:

```
from celery import Task as BaseTask

class Task(BaseTask):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
```

With this class, you can then do things like:

```
(
    Task('worker.hello').s('world') | 
    Task('messaging.email-results').s(email_address='user@company.com')
)()
```

Or, alternatively:

```
app.send_task(
    'worker.hello', ['world'], 
    chain=[
        Task('messaging.email-results').s(email_address='user@company.com')
    ]
)
```

**EDIT:**

**Disregard above**, I've since realized that the correct way to do this is by using the `Signature` class (as mentioned by @Chrismit below):

```
from celery import Signature

(
    Signature('worker.hello', args=['world']) | 
    Signature('messaging.email-results', kwargs={'email_address':'user@company.org'})
)()
```

Or, alternatively:

```
from celery import Signature

app.send_task(
    'worker.hello', ['world'], 
    chain=[
        Signature('messaging.email-results', kwargs={'email_address': 'user@company.com'})
    ]
)
```

**An important note:** Any tasks after the first task in a chain are not actually scheduled until a worker processes the task before it (this makes sense, as we don't know the input for later tasks until the previous task is run). **The subsequent tasks are scheduled on the codebase of the worker.** For this reason, you need to ensure that one of the following are true:

- each of your workers have knowledge of the `task_routes` so that it can place the followup tasks in the appropriate queue (e.g. in my example, it should know that tasks starting with `messaging.*` should go in the `'messaging'` queue)
- you have encoded the correct `queue` into each `Signature` class when you create the chain. Celery already has tooling to derive a queue name from the task name which can be leaned on:

  ```
  def get_queue_name(task_name):
      return app.amqp.router.route({}, task_name)['queue'].name

  (
      Signature('worker.hello', args=['world']) | 
      Signature(
          'messaging.email-results',
          kwargs={'email_address':'user@company.org'},
          queue=get_queue_name('messaging.email-results')  # If typing the task name twice annoys you, you could subclass Signature to do this automatically
      )
  )()
  ```

  (I think this is the cleanest solution, as it allows workers to not know about each other)
- all tasks are executed in the default queue. If you don't have any `task_routes` declared on the worker and there is no `queue` specified in the task's signature, then Celery will schedule that task in the worker's `default_queue`. Unless customized, that is `'celery'`. I strongly recommend against doing this as it isn't very explicit and doesn't allow for much queue management, but nonetheless it is an option.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is with the 'signature' function:

```
from celery import signature
chain = signature(
  'app_name.task_1',
  kwargs={..},
  queue='this_queue'
)
chain |= signature(
  'app_name2.task2',
  kwargs={..},
  queue='another_queue'
)
chain.apply_async()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:
The trick is that you have to create new signature out of you task name.

```
app.send_task("{0}.{1}".format(app_name,task),args, link = [app.signature("{0}.{1}".format(app_name,task),next_args)])
```

Comment: Now problem is linked task pass its result back to first task and I can't stop it. Any idea?

Comment: you shouldn't need to do this - you should be able to call `task.apply_async()` and have the task run on the remote machine

Comment: @scytale I scratched my head a this one initially but I think the scenario here is one where you have workers using the same broker but which have different codebases. So the tasks do not exist on all workers. So if worker A wants to launch task X which exists only on worker B, it cannot just use `task.apply_async()` because there's no `task` object to be had. It has to launch the task by name.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this signature approach didn't work for me. It created the signature object successfully though:

```
signature("some_remote_task", ...)
```

My celery version is 4.4, "some_remote_task" is defined as following:

```
    celery_app.conf.CELERY_ROUTES = {
        "some_remote_task": {
            "queue": "remote_queue",
            "routing_key": "key",
        }
    }
```

Then, I realized that the `_app=None` in the signature for some reason. After passing it like this, it worked:

```
signature("some_remote_task", app=celery_app, ...)
```

Answer (score -5):

you can use celery [canvas objects](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains).

```
from celery import chain
my_chain = chain(task1.s((arg1, arg2)), task2.s((arg3, arg4))
result = my_chain.apply_async()
```

Comment: the task is running in the remote machine and I am new in celery. How should I create task object from remote machine?

Comment: like shown - this should run the task on the remote machine